# Matanot L'Evyonim

Tags: halacha, purim, tzedakah-charity, time-zone

We must give Matanot L'Evyonim on the **day** of Purim. We can do it via a Shaliach.
If we give to a Shaliach to use in Israel for example, If they give out the money at 8 Am it is only 1 AM in North America, so we are not yet fulfilling the mitzva. If they use the funds after 3 PM (i.e. on Purim), then it is day in America and still Purim in Israel so that the Matanot L'Evyonim is being used for Purim and we would have fulfilled our obligation and no further donation would be required on Purim in America (I think). But, if the funds are used in Australia then, when they have their seuda it is either night in America or still Taanit Esther? So how could we be fulfilling giving Matanot L'Evyonim on Purim itself?

In this case, it would be given from America when we are not obligated AND used in Australia again before we are obligated. By the time morning arrives in America, Purim is over in Australia or China (unless I guess the seudah there continues throughout the night?). So would one fulfill the mitzvah of Matanot L'Evyonim via this Shaliach who gave the money to Australia or China? If we sent a cheque, then there is no Shaliach and we could not say that the Shaliach is simply an extension of "us" as if we are there so the question remains.

Do we fulfill the mitzvah of Matanot L'Evyonim if we send money for this purpose to Australia or other areas who experience night when we have Purim morning either via a Shaliach or "direct deposit"?

Comment: welcome to Mi Yodea Chaim. A big question! with an impication in Dine Shlicut (Bimkom hameshaleach, or not, but I don't believe that it is A nafka mina as in Korbanot it is not a nafka mina). May be that the response is that the zman of the Evion land is kovea because that it is the end of the Mitsva.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. The question that still is to be addressed fo rme is,  that the while it might be considered M"L for the receiver, since I am in America, then during the day of Purim, how can I rely upon someone receiving it say Last night in Australia when I do not fulful my obligation which is only during the day?  (and for those who recite shechiyanu in the morning it would have to be l'mafrai'ah shecheyanu!). In our shule we have talked about this with opposing sides. Your further insight would be appreciated....Chaim

Comment: Concerning the Chayei Adam etc. These positions are clear that the designation of the M"L on Purim to be given later is done on Purim with the money set aside for later. With respect to giving it earlier for it to arrive on Purim, it would be similar as here the Shaliach is my representative ON PURIM. I think that it would be an intesting  stretch to think that the Chayai Adam was considering shilchut to Australia or some area 12 hours away in a different time zone though with Ruach Hakodesh in writing his sefer...still,  I would not go so far. Thanks for insight

Comment: You ask for the bracha, le mafrea. Very good! Lech'ora, no. But the shaliach do not recite the bracha? Mitsvot shebegufo? No. As the Shaliach should make the bracha.

Answer (score 2):

If necessary, the Chayei Adam says you can give before Purim as long as it will be enjoyed on Purim. Alternatively, if you wake up on Purim and can't find any poor people that day, you can set aside money on Purim to be given later.

So you'd still get some mitzva if you set up a transfer on your Purim irregardless of the recipients' situation. (Whether ideal is a different question.)

Answer (score 0):

The Chasam Sofer says it is not rosh chodesh anywhere until the chodesh has been niskadesh in Eretz Yisrael, which should make it impossible to say hallel during shacharis on rosh chodesh in Australia — but it's not.

Thus the implication is that halachically (relative to global mitzva observance) we consider the world to be flat (or at least time-zone-less).

Therefore as long as your Purim mitzvos are given on Purim in the local time zone you have done your mitzva.

Comment: Please check that my edit matches your intent.