# Send Mishloach Manot to someone in a different time zone

Tags: halacha, mishloach-manot, time-zone

There are many different scenarios in this questions.

Here are a few

1. On Purim day someone living in Melbourne, Australia ask someone to deliver MM to someone in Los Angeles, USA on Purim. When it is delivered it will no longer be Purim in Australia but it is Purim in LA.
2. It is after Purim in Melbourne and someone forgot to send MM, so he gets someone to Deliver MM to someone in LA where it is still Purim.
3. On Purim day someone living in LA ask someone to deliver MM to someone in Melbourne where it is no longer Purim.

My gut tells me none of these senders are Yotze but I'm looking for some sources.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69556/matanot-levyonim